# wcf tcp.net "Could not find a base address" message

Tags: visual-studio, wcf

I am getting the error:
Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

I have read the replies for this error but still no go. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my Web.config:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
 <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfNetTcpLogService.Service1Behavior"
        name="WcfNetTcpLogService.InsertRecord">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="WcfNetTcpLogService.IInsertRecord">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8090/InsertRecord" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfNetTcpLogService.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

This Web.config almost exactly matches the example on the Microsoft web site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ff649818.aspx. The port numbers are different but I have catered for 8090 and 8523.

I am building the service on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Service Pack 1 using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 and running IIS 7.5.
Bindings http`:*:980:,net.pipe:*,net.tcp:8090:*,net.tcp:8523:*`
Enabled Protocols: http,net.tcp
Services: Net.TCP Listener Adaptor running
Windows Features: WCF Activation, HTTP Activation, Non-HTTP Activation
.NET Framework 4.5.2

My code builds successfully but when I click Start, the Microsoft WCF Test Client says:
Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

Comment: You can write a client console application that will consume this WCF service using net.tcp binding which will mimic a real world scenario. Microsoft WCF Test Client sometimes plays a bit.

Comment: Thanks Yawar. I originally went to the Test Client because when I tried to connect from a real client I got: The URI prefix is not recognized.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://<ServerDetails>:8090/WcfNetTcpLogService/InsertRecord.svc'.

Comment: After completing step 2  in msdn article that you posted in the question (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ff649818.aspx), i can call this service using Microsoft WCF Test Client with no issues. I cant see any issues with your service configuration, however you have not posted the defination of IInsertRecord interface and its implementing class.